# OpenCV contour bumps detection

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have a following problem that I want to solve:

Paper cup is photographed from it's side and it's edges and contours are found with Canny and findContours function (please see IMG1 attached bellow), then I have to test if that contour is straight (without any bumps or other imprefections) and return if it's passed or not.

**EDIT: as per  Christoph Rackwitz recomendation I'm posting original non altered image.**

I have successfully implemented edge detection as shown in IMG1 bellow, but now I want to remove parts of edges that are not used and want to get result that are shown in IMG2.

What would be the best way of doing it?
Few things that are on my mind:

- Masks (mask off other paths)
- Somehow delete paths that are radically different in x coordinates.

Yet another issue is detecting bumps on that curvy path. I'm thinking about few possible solutions:

- Loop thru contours and look for spikes in x coordinates (radical changes, from 20 to 40 for examples)
- draw similar radius arc and compare it with that contour.

The best result is shown in IMG3 image. Would be the perfect way of solving this problem for me.

**Maybe there is someone who has more expierience with OPENCV and could light up my path to solving this problem. THANK YOU!**

my code is as follow:

```
    import numpy as np 
    import cv2
    
    
    # Read the original image
    img = cv2.imread('test2.jpg') 
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3,3), 0) 
    
    
    edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=110, threshold2=180) # Canny Edge Detection
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(edges, 110, 180, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    # print(contours)
    for  cnt in contours:
        print(cv2.arcLength(cnt, False))
    
    image_copy = img.copy()
    cv2.drawContours(image=image_copy, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    
    cv2.imshow('Binary image', image_copy)
    
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: result]

***IMG1** This is what is currently detected by OpenCV*

[image: Good image with good edge detection]

***IMG2** Good edge detection that I strive to achieve*

[image: Perfect result]

***IMG3** Perfect result with combined expected path and defect in one image*

[image: Original img]

***IMG4** Original image for testing and so on*

Comment: Seems like a problem that can be solved by fitting a model to the contours you have extracted. I think you can either fit an ellipse representing the projection of the cups circumference, or a polynomial e.g. using least squares.

Comment: post the source image without any scrawlings on it. let people experiment with that data. since this is **automated optical inspection**, the approaches should be tailored to that: make sure the cup is always in the same position, take samples on that curve, do the curve fitting as suggested by NMme, now you have a simple 1D problem, which allows for simple statistics and measures (per-point deviation from best fit).